# Windows Phone 8.1 Get Geolocation by query string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows phone 8.1, I am able to do a search by geolocation using lat and long that is already known. I am then putting this into a Map Control. I was doing some research on how to just create a query string to search for something like gas stations in the area, but it does not look like the Bing SDK that I found works for Windows Phone and only the desktop store apps.

I found a method in .NET that provides you the geolocation if you provide a syntax AND a geo location (hitpoint) to give the search an idea of where from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631249.aspx). Looks like this:

```
MapLocationFinderResult result =
                await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(
                                    addressToGeocode,
                                    hintPoint,
                                    3);
```

I found another option where you reach out and provide a search via Url to virtualearth [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx)

And then there is a syntax I can't get working bingsearch:?..... I think this is deprecated, but not sure.

My question is, what is Microsoft's best practice now with phone 8.1? Also, if it is MapLocator, would you usually get the users current location and use that as the "hint point" if you aren't looking for a specific state or something that you will be going to type of thing?